# VF: custom picklist not showing vakues

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a custom picklist in my VF page, but nothing is showing in the picklist when I click on preview in the Developer Console. I am new to Salesforce and trying to understand how it works.

studentpicklist.apxc Page:

```
    public class studentpicklist {
    public string selectedValue {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> getStudents {get;set;}
    public List<selectOption> getStudents(){
        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
        options.add(new selectOption('','- None-'));
        for(Students__c student : [Select Id, Name FROM Students__c]){
            options.add(new selectOption(student.id, student.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="studentpicklist" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Student Name" for="students"></apex:outputLabel>
<apex:selectList id="students" value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" title="Student">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!getStudents}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined two get properties for Students list hence your getting empty pick list because your one get property returns empty list. try below modified code and let me know.

```
public class studentpicklist {
public string selectedValue {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> students ;
public List<selectOption> getStudents(){
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
    options.add(new selectOption('','- None-'));
    for(Students__c student : [Select Id, Name FROM Students__c]){
        options.add(new selectOption(student.id, student.Name));
    }
    return options;
}}
```

Best Regards,
-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to name the class member that's holding your `selectOptions` "getStudents" - you can change this to:

```
public List<SelectOption> students {get;set;}
```

And then when you define a getter method `getStudents`, you can change your Visualforce markup to:

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!students}"></apex:selectOptions>
```

and Visualforce will automatically call the getter you've defined (prefixing "get" to whatever the value attribute is set to, and calling that method).

The issue preventing the options from being rendered currently is that since you defined the collection as "getStudents," Visualforce is looking for a method called "getgetStudents"